# RRD Graph - Change line colour by value

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I have a RRD database with data:

```
    "DS:pkts_transmitted:GAUGE:120:0:U",
    "DS:pkts_received:GAUGE:120:0:U",
    "DS:pkts_lost:GAUGE:120:0:U",
    "DS:rtt_min:GAUGE:120:0:U",
    "DS:rtt_avg:GAUGE:120:0:U",
    "DS:rtt_max:GAUGE:120:0:U",
```

And I want that the Avg line change colour if I lose any package.

For example, if I lose 5 packets make the line blue, if I lose 10 make it red.

[image]

I see people doing it but I read the documentation and I can't find how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to actually have multiple lines defined (one of each colour) and hide the ones you don't want to see at any time, using calculations.

For example, say we have an RRD with two DSs:

```
DS:x:GAUGE:60:0:U
DS:y:GAUGE:60:0:1
```

Now, we want to show the line for `x` in red if `y` is 0, and blue if it is 1.  To do this, we create two calculated values, `x1` and `x2`.

```
CDEF:x1=y,0,EQ,x,UNKN,IF
CDEF:x2=y,1,EQ,x,UNKN,IF
```

Thus, `x1` is active if `y=0` and `x2` if `y=1`.  Yes, this could be simplified, but I'm showing it like this for the example.

Now, we can make lines using these:

```
LINE:x1#ff0000:MyLine
LINE:x2#0000ff
```

Note that the second line doesn't need a legend.  Now, the line will appear to change colour depending on the value of the `y` metric, since at any time the other line will be `UNKN` and therefore not displayed.

You can extend this, of course, to have multiple colours and more complex thresholds.

Comment: Thanks you, I done more or less the same. I have 7 item defs and with the poller just put the value in the position I need to colour and the other ones nan value.